# Get cell value from random rows based on the same content value

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want cell value from **random rows with same value (NAME)**? Example:

This fixed customer data at **11/01/2011**:

```
   Col_A    Col_B    Col_C   Col_D   Col_E  Col_F   Col_G  
R1   No     Name      etc    food    etc    drink    total
R2   1      Rossy     xxx    3       xxx    2         5
R3   2      Hayden    xxx    4       xxx    5         9
R4   3      Stoner    xxx    1       xxx    1         2
R5   4      Lorenzo   xxx    3       xxx    4         7
R6   5      Spies     xxx    0       xxx    2         2
```

and this fixed customer data at **11/02/2011**:

```
   Col_A    Col_B    Col_C   Col_D   Col_E  Col_F   Col_G  
R1   No     Name      etc    food    etc    drink    total
R2   1      Lorenzo    xxx    3      xxx    2         5
R3   2      Hayden     xxx    1      xxx    4         5
R4   3      Rossi      xxx    1      xxx    1         2
R5   4      Sic        xxx    3      xxx    1         4
R6   5      Melandry   xxx    0      xxx    2         2
R7   6      Stoner     xxx    2      xxx    3         5
```

How I can get `food` / `drink` value **based on fixed Name** when the customer name is in random rows?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you should use VLookup. Just what exactly are you tyring to do, though? total the food counts?

Comment: are the data sets for different days stored in the same sheet, different sheets in same workbook or different workbooks?

Answer (score 1):

Add a column to show the relevant date and create a pivot table, with formula = food/drink (if that ratio is really what you want!, and your data is all in the one sheet, and ....)

[image: Pivot]